# Ubuntu 17.10 does not get up

Tags: boot, 17.10

I have Ubuntu 17.10 working on Asus prime B250M-A motherboard with Intel i7-7700 CPU and integrated graphics which recently has issues with switching off and getting up (it freezes on splash screen). I am continuously installing new updates counting that this will solve the issue but it does not. I do not have even idea where to search the issue. For additional info. This is my disk partitioning:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 119,2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: ***

Urządzenie    Start    Koniec   Sektory   Size Typ
/dev/sda1      2048    999423    997376   487M EFI System
/dev/sda2    999424  17006591  16007168   7,6G Linux swap
/dev/sda3  17006592 250068991 233062400 111,1G Linux filesystem
```

I have home folder encrypted. If I should paste anything from my syslog, I'll of course do it, but as I say: for now I do not even know what to search for.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently system is getting up and shutting down flawlessly, so since I still haven't figured out what was wrong all I can suggest is to update either with update manager or from console with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`.